# Как добавить прозрачный цветной градиент в изображение с помощью PIL?

Tags: python, pil

Пытаюсь сделать следующим образом:

```
from PIL import Image


path_to_image = "image.png"

im = Image.open(path_to_image)
im = im.convert('RGBA')
width, height = im.size
gradient = Image.new('L', (1, height), color="#ff6347")

for y in range(height):
    gradient.putpixel((0, height-1 - y), y)
    alpha = gradient.resize(im.size)
    im.putalpha(alpha)

im.save('test.png', 'PNG')
```

Но градиент получается, да, с альфа, каналом, но только черно-белый. Аргумент `color` в `Image.new(..., ..., color="#ff6347")` просто игнорируется. Что не так?

Comment: Альфа-слой это же просто прозрачность, откуда там цвет?

Comment: Причем здесь альфа канал?

Comment: А что по вашему делает функция `Image.putalpha(alpha)`? *"Adds or replaces the alpha layer in this image."*